# CSV file contents to two dimensional array

Tags: c#, csv, multidimensional-array

This question has been asked several times with different inputs so I thought of reposting it with my requirement.

I have a CSV file which contents string fields in the way given below.

```
idnum,name1, name2,groupid

idnum,name1, name2,groupid

idnum,name1, name2,groupid
```

example

```
s001,sahil,payap,gid0

s002,Amir,Khan,gid02

d003,hrithik,roshan,gid03
```

I have two dimensional string array. I want to read row by row to my two dimensional array.
When it read it should be like this

```
arr[0][0]=s001

arr[0][1]=name1

arr[0][2]=name2

arr[0][3]=gid01

arr[1][0]=s002

arr[1][1]=Amir

arr[1][2]=Khan

arr[1][3]=gid04
```

there are 40 records in a file and it should read till the end of the file.
I need to implement this in C#

Any code sample or any explanation would be great help.

I have no knowledge in csv file handling so please don't ask what did you try, at least if you could give me a code sample for reading just one string for a variable it would be a great help.
And please don't ask to go for another solution. 
Thanks.

Comment: What have you *tried*? What worked? What didn't?

Comment: If i was you I'd read each record into a struct, multi-dimensional arrays are confusing as hell for people reviewing your code.

Comment: @Piskvor NO sir I didnt try any as I don't have a clue on that. Can you get me a code sample at least to read a single string from a csv file to a string variable..

Comment: @Ashigore No currently I have not thought of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file would have to be read in line-wise. Each line would have to be separated using `String.Split`. Then the resulting strings would have to be trimmed using `Trim`, and finally would have to be written into the respective columns of the current row. However I totally second the comments above; more convenient would be to use some class or struct called `Person` and then to parse into a `List<Person>`.

The reading could be done as follows:

```
String line = String.Empty;
System.IO.StreamReader file =  new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\file.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    String[] parts_of_line = line.Split(',')
    for ( int i = 0; i < parts_of_line.Length; i++ )
        parts_of_line[i] = parts_of_line[i].Trim();

    // do with the parts of the line whatever you like

}
```

Comment: can you show me the way just to do at least for a single line?
Or just read a single string line in a csv file to a variable..

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to read a csv file in the way you suggest is probably:

```
var rows = File.ReadAllLines("myfile.csv").Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Then:

```
Console.WriteLine(rows[0][0]); // Will output s001
Console.WriteLine(rows[0][1]); // Will output sahil
Console.WriteLine(rows[0][2]); // Will output payap
Console.WriteLine(rows[0][3]); // Will output gid0
Console.WriteLine(rows[1][0]); // Will output s002
Console.WriteLine(rows[2][0]); // Will output d003
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that using the [CsvHelper library](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/):

```
const string Csv = @"s001,sahil,payap,gid0
s002,Amir,Khan,gid02
d003,hrithik,roshan,gid03";

var rows = new List<string[]>();
string[] row;

using (var stringReader = new StringReader(Csv))
using (var parser = new CsvParser(stringReader))
while ((row = parser.Read()) != null)
{
    rows.Add(row);
}

Console.WriteLine(rows[0][0]); // Will output s001
Console.WriteLine(rows[0][1]); // Will output sahil
Console.WriteLine(rows[0][2]); // Will output payap
Console.WriteLine(rows[0][3]); // Will output gid0
Console.WriteLine(rows[1][0]); // Will output s002
Console.WriteLine(rows[2][0]); // Will output d003
```

For a working example, check out this .NET fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/PLPXo8

If you want to read directly from file, you can do this:

```
var rows = new List<string[]>();
string[] row;

using (var parser = new CsvParser(File.OpenText(@"c:\test.csv")))
while ((row = parser.Read()) != null)
{
      rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks
but I would like a little bit explanation,
What is that csv string for? is that the line for ?
//This line 
//const string Csv = @"s001,sahil,payap,gid0
s002,Amir,Khan,gid02
d003,hrithik,roshan,gid03"; i want to open file and read row by row, so is this the line to locate the file.?
confused with this line too? 
var rows = new List<string[]>();
why use array in <>?
I plan to do the out puit in a different way so I don't need the way to out put the array contents but I want clear explanations for how to read in to array. Any sites to refer as a tutorial? in CSV file reading?

Comment: @user3572467 SO isn't here to teach you how to code. You ask a specific question and get specific answers.

Comment: @Ashigore yes sir true but is that's the case I would like to have little bit explanation.

Comment: Well, the `Csv` variable is only there for illustration purposes. I have updated the sample to show how to directly read from a file.